# Create an animation effect with Java 2D

Tags: java, java-2d

Look at the background of this game [image]
<sub>(source: [xbox.com](http://download.xbox.com/content/images/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d80258410a03/1033/screenlg7.jpg))</sub>

Is possible create that dark effect with Java 2D ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is possible create that dark effect with Java 2D ?

In any number of ways. The simplest is to have a BG image that is the dark BG, and paint that before the rest of the GUI.